# CDN - Serve different content-type based on Accept header (Verizon/EdgeCast Premium)?

Tags: azure, cdn, edgecast, verizon

I have a server which returns a different response based on the Accept header e.g. if Accept header includes "image/webp", a webp image is served, otherwise a jpg is served.

We run Varnish at server-level and it does this correctly, as per example below:

Request (with image/webp in Accept header):

```
curl -s -D - -o /dev/null "https://REDACTED/media/tokinoha_bowl-4.jpg?sh=2&fmt=webp,jpg" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
```

Response (webp image served):

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 08:25:05 GMT
content-type: image/webp
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, s-maxage=31536000, max-age=31536000
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding,Origin
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 60028
```

Request (no webp in Accept header, jpg served):

```
curl -s -D - -o /dev/null "https://REDACTED/media/tokinoha_bowl-4.jpg?sh=2&fmt=webp,jpg" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
```

Response:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 08:25:18 GMT
content-type: image/jpeg
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: public, s-maxage=31536000, max-age=31536000
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding,Origin
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 166991
```

We have the below options in the Rules Engine set up, however whichever content-type is cached first is served on all subsequent requests irrespective of request header.

Rules Engine settings

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem with `Verizon/Edgecast:` One URL delivered two different image types (`JPEG` and `WebP`) depending on `Accept` header. The origin (imgix) sent correctly `Vary: Accept`, but `Edgecast` ignored that and cached what it get and so browsers without `WebP` support got sometimes the wrong format.

We solved it with a rule in Edgecast:
[WebP rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V35o.png)

The query parameter `auto` is always part of the `URL` and can therefore always be removed from the cache key. With the second query parameter `varyWebP` we recognize the URLs definitely and prevent a collision with URLs without query parameter `auto`.

In this case the URL

```
https://[HOST]/[PATH]?a=1&b=2&c=3&auto=compress,format
```

creates the same cache key as:

```
https://[HOST]/[PATH]?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

That's why the query parameter `varyWebP` protects us.